# Simulated annealing algorithm to solve the traveling salesman problem in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, traveling-salesman, simulated-annealing

So im trying to solve the traveling salesman problem using simulated annealing. I am given a 100x100 matrix that contains the distances between each city, for example, [0][0] would contain 0 since the distances between the first city and itself is 0, [0][1] contains the distance between the first and the second city and so on.

My problem is, the code ive written does not minimize the tour distance, it gets stuck in a range of numbers and never gets to minimize correctly until the temperature reaches 0. I tried doing the same problem with a hill climbing algorithm and it worked fine, but i cant seem to make it work with simulated annealing. Can someone help me see what im doing wrong?

```
Mat = distancesFromCoords() #returns the 100x100 matrix with distances
T = 10000 #temperature
Alpha = 0.98 #decreasing factor
X = [i for i in range(99)] #random initial tour
random.shuffle(X)
X.append(X[0])    

while T > 0.01:
    Z = nuevoZ(X,Mat) #Best current solution
    Xp = copy.deepcopy(X)          
    a = random.sample(range(1,98),2)
    Xp[a[0]], Xp[a[1]] = Xp[a[1]],Xp[a[0]]   
    Zp = nuevoZ(Xp,Mat)  #Probable better solution

    decimal.setcontext(decimal.Context(prec=5))
    deltaZ = Zp - Z
    Prob = decimal.Decimal(-deltaZ/T).exp()

    print("probabilidad: ", Prob)
    print("Temperatura: ",T)
    print("Z: ",Z)
    print("Zp: ",Zp)
    print("\n")

    if Zp < Z:
        X = Xp
        T = T*Alpha
    else:
        num = randint(0,1)
        if num<Prob:
            X = copy.copy(Xp)
            T = T*Alpha
```

functions used in the algorithm:

```
def nuevoZ(X, Mat):
Z = 0
for i in range(len(X)-1):
    Z = Z + Mat[X[i]][X[i+1]] 
return Z  #returns a new solution given the tour X and the City Matrix.


def distancesFromCoords():  #gets the matrix from a text file.
f = open('kroA100.tsp')
data = [line.replace("\n","").split(" ")[1:] for line in f.readlines()[6:106]]
coords =  list(map(lambda x: [float(x[0]),float(x[1])], data))
distances = []
for i in range(len(coords)):
    row = []
    for j in range(len(coords)):
        row.append(math.sqrt((coords[i][0]-coords[j][0])**2 + (coords[i][1]-coords[j][1])**2))
    distances.append(row)
return distances
```

Comment: Good luck in solving TSP. :)

Comment: Take a look at the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55699719/5976530

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/frigidum/

Contains an example for TSP (442 cities).

It is good practice (like in example) to use local_search_2opt after SA has found a potential solution.

If it doesn't converge:

1. Check that indeed the acceptance function is *always* accepting shorter, and longer solutions with a probability
2. Check that in the first few proposals, most proposals are accepted, even when they are worse. If this is not the case, the initial temperature is not high enough.
3. Check that the proposals are working. You might want to print/debug the difference in the global minimum for each proposal in a round.